# Java two labels on one loop

Tags: java, loops

I know that you can use loop labels in the following way:

```
foo:
while (something) {
    // ...
    while (somethingElse) {
        if (yetAnotherCondition) {
            break foo;
        }
    }
}
```

However, I noticed that it is not a syntactical error to have two labels for one loop. An example (I know the labels are unnecessary, and the loop only executes once, but just to show the allowance of two labels on one loop):

```
foo:
bar:
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    break foo;
}
```

Runs equivalently to

```
foo:
bar:
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    break bar;
}
```

Does anyone know when you would need two labels for only one loop? I expected a compilation error when running this, but didn't get one.

Comment: Labels are arbitrary, and (outside of `switch` statements) they're really intended to be used in nested loops.

Comment: You wouldn't need it, but they never bothered to disallow it, so the compiler accepts it.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have 2 different outcomes that need to break to different code.  During testing you may end up commenting out the code in between.  This way it still works instead of breaking.